# How to get element of dropdown list from JSP

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, jstl

I have one User class,

```
//UserDAO
private String name;
private String[] certifications;

//getters and setters here....
```

Controller.java

```
List<UserDAO> usersList= new ArrayList<UserDAO>();
UserDAO userOne = new UserDAO();
userOne.setName("user1");
userOne.setCertifications({"cert1"});

UserDAO userTwo = new UserDAO();
userTwo.setName("user1");
userTwo.setCertifications({"cert1","cert2"});

usersList.add(userOne);
usersList.add(userTwo);

model.addAttribute("usersList", usersList);
```

JSP

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${usersList}">
    <tr>
        <td>"${list.name}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="${list.name}"/></td>
        <td>
        <select>
        <c:forEach var="rowSelect" items="${list.certifications}">  
        <option value = "${rowItemSelect}">${rowItemSelect}</option>    
        </c:forEach>                                                                                                    
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Above code populates data correctly. Please tell how to send the selected dropdown value for certification in JSP and how to access these values in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place your select dropdown in a `<form>` and when the form is submitted the corresponding setter should be called.

You have to give a name to your `<select>` tag so that the framework knows which variable to assign the `<option>` value to. If you want to send the value back to `myName` variable then your `<select>` should look like this

```
<select name="myName">
```

Comment: I tried <form:select name="dropdown"> <form:options items="${list.certifications}"/> </form:select>. But now my I am not able to view JSP. Error says that attribute path is mandatory for tag select. I tried to put path="certifications", still there is an error.